# Hora no formato do PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

estou criando uma função no wordpress para agendar eventos da seguinte maneira:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'prefix_setup_schedule' );
function prefix_setup_schedule() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'send_email' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'send_email');
    }
}
```

Só que esse time teria que ser às 18 horas e não a hora que fosse registrado, então, queria fazer com que pegasse o dia atual e a hora sempre as 18 nesse formato do time para que não haja problemas na função;

Alguma solução?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função [`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) retorna o *timestamp* atual. Se você quer criar um *timestamp* às 18h da data atual, o código do `time()` seria assim:

```
strtotime(date("Y-m-d 18:00:00"));
```

Comment: isso mesmo, valeu @amauri :D

Comment: Espero ter ajudado, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como respondida caso tenha dado tudo certo, Abs